# Javascript setting value of textbox by function, without getting reset

Tags: javascript

My goal is to have a text box and a button. If I enter "Hello" in the text box and press the submit button I would like to have see the text box filled with "World.

For the moment the value of the text box will be changed betweeen  the

```
<html>
   <body>
         <script>
            function validateForm() {
                var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Input"].value;
                if (x == "Hello") {
                    alert("test");
                    document.getElementById("Input").value = "World";
                    alert("test2");
                }
            }
        </script>

        <form name="myForm" action="test.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Input: <input type="text" id="Input"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: I tried the code locally (Firefox and Chrome) and the text box gets filles with "World"

Comment: I'm running it on my Windows 10 machine with chrome and the field is empty once i click away the second alert message. Could it be the extension of my html file is wrong? I'm saving my code in a .html file and just open it in my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the form gets submitted right after the validation. So you are redirected to `test.html` again.

If you don't want that to happen, add `event.preventDefault();` to your Event Handler ([check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ah6r8nf6/) to see it working):

```
<html>
   <body>
         <script>
            function validateForm(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Input"].value;
                if (x == "Hello") {
                    alert("test");
                    document.getElementById("Input").value = "World";
                    alert("test2");
                }
            }
        </script>

        <form name="myForm" action="test.html" onsubmit="return validateForm(event)" method="post">
        Input: <input type="text" id="Input"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

You can [learn more about `event.preventDefault()` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

*Just as a sidenote:* It is generally better to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the `onsubmit` attribute (Better separation of concerns, you can add multiple event listeners, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your page, then the content in the action page will be loaded.

In your case test.html will be loaded.

If you want the value "World" to be shown in the text box on hitting the submit, then return false on your validateForm() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false;` to stay on the same page and stop form submission.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Input"].value;
    if (x == "Hello") {
        document.getElementById("Input").value = "World";
        return false;
    }
}
```